# File transfer failing with WebLogic? java.io.IOException: failed to read '2607' bytes from InputStream

Tags: java, internet-explorer, weblogic, file-transfer

we have a WebLogic application serving PDF files (among many other things).

We have problem such that sometimes some of the files seem to fail when loaded with Internet Explorer.

- WebLogic version 10.3.3.0
- IE 8.0 tested so far positive
- Problems also with Firefox

  - It might be that there were some files that had problems with IE but didn't have problems with Firefox (not 100% sure)
- Seems to happen for some files (at least for a couple of times) with different computers
- Most of the files work fine
- PDF files are generated beforehand and available at the file system.

At these errors, we get the following stack trace:

```
####<Aug 16, 2012 10:30:26 AM EEST> <Error> <HTTP> <host-name> <Front2S> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1345102226691> <WL-101019> <[ServletContext@454961994[app:appname module:modulename path:/pathname spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with IOException
java.io.IOException: failed to read '2607' bytes from InputStream; clen: 162774 remaining: 2607 count: 1359
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeStream(ChunkOutput.java:417)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.writeStream(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:178)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeStream(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeStream(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:508)
        at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.sendFile(FileServlet.java:410)
        at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.doGetHeadPost(FileServlet.java:234)
        at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.service(FileServlet.java:173)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    ...
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:151)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:168)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

With some googling, I've found that something like this could happen if the file is modified during the transfer.

- At least we can't see how this could happen (the script generating the files runs at night and the errors are got at the daytime)
- This also happens multiple times for partifular files

Long time ago, we had similar issue with WebLogic file metadata caching but disabling metadata caching fixed that.

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:resource-reload-check-secs>0</wls:resource-reload-check-secs>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Some ideas?

Br, Touko

Answer (score 3):

You are right regarding the error cause. The issue happens when the file is modified while it is being read.

Your configuration of the resource-reload-check-secs is correct. Keep it to 0 (zero) so that WLS will reload the latest file.

Check if you are using the page-check-seconds setting and whether the setting's value is 0. This setting **overrides** the resource-reload-check-secs so in case you have a value different than 0 (zero) then set it to 0.

In conclusion my proposal is to add the **page-check-seconds** setting with value 0 in weblogic.xml and **increase the weblogic.Chunksize** in case you have large request sizes. The property's value should be multiples of the network’s MTU after subtracting any Ethernet or TCP header sizes.

I hope the following configuration of weblogic.xml will help you:

```
<jsp-descriptor>
    <page-check-seconds>0</page-check-seconds>
</jsp-descriptor>
<container-descriptor>
    <resource-reload-check-secs>0</resource-reload-check-secs>
</container-descriptor>
```

Furthermore please note that there are patch fixes for this issue.

Comment: We aren't using page-check-seconds setting ATM, got to consider setting it to 0 explicitly. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that except the page-check-seconds configuration maybe you could also consider increasing the -Dweblogic.Chunksize if the request sizes are large. The property's value should be multiples of the network’s MTU after subtracting any Ethernet or TCP header sizes.